# How to align sectors of a cirlce in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm new to Adobe Illustrator. I'm trying to recreate a logo in vector graphics. The logo has a circle background and 4 sectors overlaid kind of like below. I've created the four sections by using the ellipse tool and creating a section at 45 degree angles but I can't seem to get them to line up, the cross going through the middle tapers towards the outside and it looks terrible. How would I get the sections to line up so that it looks like there's a perfect X going through the centre of the circle?

[image: logo example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are probably wasting your time trying to line those up. Time to try a simpler technique.

1. Switch on Smart Guides
2. Place a vertical and horizontal guide to give you a guide to centre everything on.
3. Draw a circle with the centre at the intersection of the guides, add a blue stroke, no fill.
4. Then choose the line tool, draw a horzontal line through the centre from one side of the circle to the other.
5. Do Object > Transform > Rotate, set it to 45 degrees
6. Copy, then Paste in Front.
7. Do Object > Transform > Rotate, set it to 90 degrees.
8. Select all, then do Object > Live Paint > Make.
9. Use the Live Paint Bucket, select a colour, fill in the segments.

The result is pretty good, and the lines are perfect.

[image]

Not only that, but since the Live Paint object is "live" - you can set the stroke to any size you want.

[image]

Comment: This is The Right Answer, but I think you left out a 45° rotation somewhere. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I just drew the the first straight line by eye at approx 45 degrees, but of course you could draw a horizontal line using the guides and rotate to 45 degrees for an exact angle. But you're right, I edited the steps.. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: If you hold shift down it will align drawing to 45 degree increments ;)

Comment: @jooja , yup, that too!

Comment: I draw a line, horizontal or vertical, copy, paste it in place, rotate 90, select Both lines and rotate 45 to get the perfect X shape. I would use this to Divide the circle above to achieve the result the poster asked for.

Comment: @Webster - so why not write your own answer?  There are many ways to skin a cat!

Answer (score 1):

You can draw that in a few seconds pretty easily...

- Smart Guides (*View → Smart Guides*) will allow you to snap to the center of objects
- Holding <kbd>alt</kbd> while creating shapes will allow you to draw those shapes from their center
- Holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while drawing will constrain the drawing to 90 and 45 degree angles

So...

1. Draw a circle
2. Draw a line at 45 degress from the center of (and slightly overshooting) the circle
3. Draw the other line
4. Select all
5. Pathfinder Divide

[image]

You can adjust the stroke to change the "gap" between segments and outline that stroke (*Object → Path → Outline Stroke*) if needs be.